# backup sqlserver db only tape available

Tags: sql-server-2012

not sure whats happened to our sql server but for some reason when I right click on a db -> tasks ->backup it will only allow me to back it up to a Tape

I used to be able to just back it up to a dir on the hard drive.

Does anyone know what I've done? or can do to sort it?

Were running sqlserver 2012

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the hard drive as a backup "device".

It is pretty easy, and as you might guess, in the manual :)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189109(v=sql.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189109%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

Like a lot of this maintenance stuff, the point is if you are managing multiple databases, you might reuse this "device" in multiple backup jobs.
If you just have one db, it might seem unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for that but I'm not sure you understand me, I want to make a backup of a db (.bak) so I can use it on another server.

Comment: DOH if you select the radio button "Disk" you then get the option to save the backup to disk

Comment: good :)
You can also make the disk "device" if you want it to show up in that list.  But obviously it may not be useful.

Comment: Also, you if you want to note what you found, you can add your own answer, even though it's your question (you won't get "points")

Answer (score 0):

if you select the radio button "Disk" you then get the option to save the backup to disk –